# glmmTMB for non-regression ecological count data?

Tags: regression, r, generalized-linear-model, ecology, glmmtmb

Study design: I am analyzing ecological count data for fish in a pre-existing database with observations of fish species abundances(zero_filled). Each species were recorded at a site twice a month of a given year. The recorded years are not a regression-they were chosen based on warmest on the record and coldest on the record. The main purpose of the study is to analyze if biodiversity of fish has been impacted by temperature over long-term.
So you have factors: 'Years','Site','Group','Species' and numeric response of 'counts'.

I care mostly whether the counts depend on the temp group, but I'm unsure if years will be an interaction.
Since they are counts, there are many zeros present and I assume a negative binomial or zero-inflated model to be the most appropriate.
I've only ever worked with regressions models, and most examples out there for counts are regression as well.
Is glmmTMB still appropriate to use for this type of data.

Comment: "The recorded years are not a regression-they were chosen based on warmest on the record and coldest on the record. " - what does this mean? Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Its a preexisting dataset of 20+ years of seining abundance community counts. Im interested in anomaly years(i.e warmer and colder years of that record). Only 12 years(6 for each group) were chosen to analyze community counts. So the years are not back to back, and skips blocks of time. So the coldest years could be 1999, 2004, 2009, 2015...etc.

Comment: OK. I still don't really understand what "not a regression" means, but I think I understand what you are trying to do. Yes you can use glmmTMB. Is there a reason why you can't just use the full dataset, append temperature onto each year, and then use temperature as a predictor in the model? The magnitude and direction of the temperature coefficient would presumably give you insight on the effect of temperature on biodiversity.

Comment: You may want to experiment with a response variable other than abundance too, as abundances are usually suuuper variable and hard to model / hard to draw useful conclusion from. Often, species richness or shannon entropy can be easier to model

Comment: I'm likely misunderstanding it with relation to a time series, but thank you for the help. The full data cannot be used as looking at the full time series no longer focuses on the temperature anomalies in it, and I am also doing additional tests for alpha and beta diversity. It would simply be too time consuming with my time frame.